# Form searching issue php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In simple form given below,if we search something it look in browser like this:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YEJz.png
```

with form code:

```
<form name="newad" method="get"  action="search.php">
<h1 align="center"> Type your query<input type="text" name="text">
<h1 align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" >
</form>
```

Now,somehow i want to change original query means,if we search 'partner food' as in above example,it should be converted to md5 and fetch data as we are storing in ,so it should look like `http://localhost/robbin.php?text=B9B5A976F29A3C71EDAD9320A9AB0982&Submit=Submit+Query`
.But it is not working like this.
I tried like this:

```
$submit=$_GET['text'];
$encrypted=md5($submit);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%$encrypted%'");
```

Pls specify what should i do?

Comment: you want to show encrypted keywords in browser or only want to search it your database?  
If you only want to search in DB,then your approach is right

Comment: I want to search encrypted word in database,as based on query,and if approach is rgiht then why it is not searching,means only searching the term.

Comment: btw if you are displaying your keywords as plain text in browser,why are you stroking them in DB as encrypted?  I don't think its right approach.  Check your column size. Sometimes after encryption string becomes longer and DB stored few character of that encrypted string if your column size is less.

Comment: Somehow,it is important to store them in db as encrypted and then fecthing is as per encrypted but not working.Pls suggest any help or likn.

Comment: I guess another Question already asked by someone will help you.


http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/how-to-search-a-mysql-database-with-encrypted-fields

Comment: It should be noted that md5 isn't encrypted it's hashed, which is very different. hashed values are non-reversible where as encrypted values are with the appropriate key. They are also susceptible to collisions, meaning two words/phrases can hash to the same value.

Comment: Forget md5 or whatever,main problem is why script is still searching submit value,not the modified i.e. encrypted in this case?

Comment: In your question, you didn't say that it was searching for the plain text instead of the hashed value. If the code above is correct and complete, then the query should be using the hashed value. I guess the obvious thing to do would be to echo the value of `$encrypted` and also create a variable holding the query string and echo that. That should make it fairly obvious why the query is failing.

Comment: @Steve can you refer any external source?

Comment: Nothing clever that would need any external reference - I just meant: `echo $encrypted;` and the same for the query string, into the HTML of your web page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I didn't misunderstand your question.

If you wanna change `partner food` to encrypted text and then send by GET method, you have to encrypt text field in Client Side first, I mean use jQuery or Java Script for encryption in client side, and then send it.

PHP is Server Side language, and also `md5()` only can encrypt data, and you can't decipher data that is encrypted by `md5()`.

I recommend you to use another functions that could be decipher like `base64` or something else like that.

Also if you use encrypted data in MySQL and you want to search that, you don't need `LIKE` statement, change your query to:

`SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent = '$encrypted'`

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

In short: You don't wanna hash or encrypt anything client-side as it can be messed with easily (and the algorithm suddenly is heavily dependent on the browser). What's wrong with sending the actual search query, then hash/encrypt it server-side?

Anyway, as @Anderss0n stated, you could use base64 instead. Or, if you REALLY want to do a MD5-hash, consider either

1) Doing an Ajax call to a simple PHP-script returning the md5 of what it received:

```
return md5($_POST['encrypt_this_string']);
```

or

2) check this library out: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ - it exposes an `CryptoJS` object which has a function called `MD5`

Comment: I would go with number 2. You just have to include the js-file with a `<script src="...."></script>` tag.